# Can SXA redirect map entries redirect from a Sitecore URL to an external one?

Tags: sxa, redirect

The title more or less says it all.  Having trouble figuring out how to redirect a Sitecore address to an external website URL, or if that's something that the SXA redirect map is capable of doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, **Redirect Map** can only redirect to other items on a current site (it will try to append to a URL string that you define in the mapping).

### Redirect Map + Redirect Item

Although it is not a perfect solution you could redirect to an existing **Redirect Item** ([Redirect a URL](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/search/redirect_a_url)) and define external URL there.

One important thing about **Redirect Map**. It will match your URL only if Sitecore is unable to resolve the item (404), otherwise, it will return the item.

### Wildcard Item / Redirect Item

This is an interesting solution but it will not work for every case. You can try to combine wildcards feature with **Redirect Item**

[image]

This will match every URL that cannot be resolved on a first level and redirect to google

#### Documentation:

- [Map a URL redirect](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/search/map_a_url_redirect)
- [Redirect a URL](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/search/redirect_a_url)